# How to update some row where ID = SELECT (...) - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table - "logs".

```
+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+
| logId | spName | startTime | executionTime |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+
|  1    | mail   | 11:54:49  |    300        |
|  2    | calc   | 13:12:11  |    500        |
| ....  |        |           |               |
|  100  | log    | 15:30:30  |    400        |
+-------+--------+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to update it like:

```
UPDATE logs 
SET executionTime = 600
WHERE logId = ( SELECT max(logId) FROM logs WHERE spName = 'calc' )
```

But I receive an error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'logs' for update in FROM clause

I don't know how to fix it(

Comment: why do u need max(logId).?

Comment: 600 WHERE spname = 'calc' ORDER BY logid DESC LIMIT 1; ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with single query by using ORDER By and LIMIT

```
UPDATE logs 
SET executionTime = 600
WHERE spName = 'calc'
ORDER By logId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This will update only one row with largest logId

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE logs a,
(SELECT SELECT max(logId) max_logs FROM logs WHERE spName = 'calc') AS b
SET executionTime = 600
WHERE a.logId = b.max_logs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join update for this

```
update logs l1
join (
 select max(logId) from logs WHERE spName = 'calc'
)l2 on l1.logId = l2.logId
set l1.executionTime = 600
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE logs 
SET executionTime = 600
WHERE logId = ( SELECT logId FROM logs WHERE spName = 'calc' )
```

Comment: This will return error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause